# A get or set accessor expected

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting get or set accessor excepted

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\KARTHICK\Documents\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into table1 values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("record inserted successfully");
        }
        public void display
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from table1";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt=new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter dt= new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.fill(dt);
            con.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing `()` after the function name on `public void display`

Comment: Can you add some descriptions to your code?

Comment: Getting the error at what line? BTW, ever heard of [sql injection attacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes:

1. Add `()` to the end of `public void display`
2. Duplicate variable named `dt` at `SqlDataAdapter dt= new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);`
3. `da` variable is not defined at `da.fill(dt);`